# Is it possible to import a Xcode framework in Monotouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, frameworks, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to import a Xcode framework To Monotouch?? (if so, how can I do it??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by **import** you mean being able to use the frameworks provided by iOS then **YES** you can be either:

a) use what's already provided by MonoTouch - i.e. most of the API provided by Apple are already binded and provided;

b) creating the binding yourself - anything missing (e.g. new stuff) or third-parties libraries/frameworks can be bound using the **btouch** tool [1] (for ObjectiveC code) or using .NET p/invoke mechanism.

[1] http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types

Comment: Thanks, this post is what I was looking for http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Linking_Native_Libraries I found it because of your link!